# image upload with Magento Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cdn, loadbalancing

My Magento store is configured with Elastic Load Balancer but when i try to upload product images from the backend sometimes it fails.

I have IP

- `192.168.2.1` - A
- `192.168.2.2` - B

My problem is there are times that images are uploaded to server B and magento fails to locate the images.

My Site is equiped with:

- Elastic Load Balancer
- CDN
- AWS

please help its been two months since i started to face this problem. I new to server staff and only follow tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a unique URL that resolves to only one of your servers for Admin. The admin server should be the master server where the content originates from. For example, when you do code updates, do you upload to server A?

The point is that content is uploaded to one point then disseminated across your network. What is most likely happening is that you are periodically uploading to a server that is not syncing to the other server.